# Text in a graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs

I have the following code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [auto,
 vertex/.style={circle,draw=black!100,fill=black!100,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm}]
\node (v1) at ( 1,1) [vertex,label=left:$v_1$] {};
\node (v2) at ( 0,0) [vertex,label=left:$v_2$] {};
\node (v3) at ( 2,0) [vertex,label=right:$v_3$] {};
\draw [-] (v1) to (v2);
\draw [-] (v2) to (v3);
\draw [-] (v1) to (v3);
\draw [-] [loop below] (v1) to (v1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now this draws my graph nicely with three vertices. My problem is that I want to give names to the edges v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_1v_3,v_1v_1 as e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4 respectively. These names should be positioned near the edges. Moreover I want TikZ to place the names for these edges automatically without disturbing each other and without me specifying the positions. What is the best way to accomplish this? I think auto is used for this but am not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, vertex/.style={circle,draw=black!100,fill=black!100, thick,
                inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm}]
\node (v1) at ( 1,1) [vertex,label=left:$v_1$] {};
\node (v2) at ( 0,0) [vertex,label=left:$v_2$] {};
\node (v3) at ( 2,0) [vertex,label=right:$v_3$] {};
\draw [-] (v1) --node[inner sep=0pt,swap]{$e_1$} (v2);
\draw [-] (v2) --node[inner sep=2pt,swap]{$e_2$} (v3);
\draw [-] (v1) --node[inner sep=0pt]{$e_3$} (v3);
\draw [-] [loop below] (v1) to node[inner sep=0pt]{$e_4$} (v1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]